# angularJS script file not working when called in html

Tags: html, angularjs

Only the html output and the {{10 + 10}} of the web page is rendered.  I'm not sure what what I'm doing wrong but I'm guessing it's some setup type issue in my visual studio project.

```
(function () {
  var app = angular.module("ShipmentsHome", []);

  var EditShipmentsController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "--Still need to create grid here--";
  };

  app.controller("EditShipmentsController", ["$scope", EditShipmentsController]);
}());
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Shipments Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../../lib/home.js"></script>
</head>

  <body ng-app="ShipmentsHome" ng-controller="EditShipmentsController">
    <h1>Product Transfers</h1>
    <p>Create or modify a transfer below:</p>
    <div> {{message}}</div>
    <p>look above for message from controller</p>
    <h2>{{10 + 10}}</h2>



  </body>
</html>
```

I am not seeing any errors in the console. Below is what I am seeing:
[image]

Comment: Its working fine for me https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4YCQC8V2CVM   Please check for any typos in your code

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem will be with your relative path. I got it working when I replace the script source with the actual controller script. please check your path and correct it.

Comment: The path is fine and this is working in plunker for me.  I dragged and dropped the script path from the object explorer so unless there is a bug in Visual Studio around their drag and drop functionality I doubt that's the issue.  Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the project I was working with was setup to use .ts files and not .js files.  I needed to create the project to work with angularjs not typescript.